# How to optimize below spark code (scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, optimization, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have some huge files (of 19GB, 40GB etc.). I need to execute following algorithm on these files:

1. Read the file
2. Sort it on the basis of 1 column
3. Take 1st 70% of the data:

   a) Take all the **distinct** records of the subset of the columns
    b) write it to **train file**
4. Take the last 30% of the data:

   a) Take all the **distinct** records of the subset of the columns

   b) write it to **test file**

I tried running following code in spark (using Scala).

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

import java.io.FileWriter

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.year

    val offers = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .load("input.txt")
    val csvOuterJoin = offers.orderBy("utcDate")
    val trainDF = csvOuterJoin.limit((csvOuterJoin.count*.7).toInt)
    val maxTimeTrain = trainDF.agg(max("utcDate"))
    val maxtimeStamp = maxTimeTrain.collect()(0).getTimestamp(0)
    val testDF = csvOuterJoin.filter(csvOuterJoin("utcDate") > maxtimeStamp)    
    val inputTrain = trainDF.select("offerIdClicks","userIdClicks","userIdOffers","offerIdOffers").distinct
    val inputTest = testDF.select("offerIdClicks","userIdClicks","userIdOffers","offerIdOffers").distinct
    inputTrain.rdd.coalesce(1,false).saveAsTextFile("train.csv")
    inputTest.rdd.coalesce(1,false).saveAsTextFile("test.csv")
```

This is how I initiate spark-shell:

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0 --total-executor-cores 70 --executor-memory 10G --driver-memory 20G
```

I execute this code on a distributed cluster with 1 master and many slaves each having sufficient amount of RAM. As of now, this code ends up taking a lot of memory and I get java heap space issues.

Is there a way to optimize the above code (preferably in spark)? I appreciate any kind of minimal help in optimizing the above code.

Comment: This doesn't explicitly solve your issue, so I'll leave it as a comment. There is a `dataframe.randomSplit()` function that allows you to split a dataframe (albeit randomly) into fractional pieces that you specify. Keep it in mind for the future!

Comment: I was looking for temporal split rather than random split. But it is good to know that dataframe.randomSplit() exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you don't distribute at all. And the source is here:

```
val csvOuterJoin = offers.orderBy("utcDate")
val trainDF = csvOuterJoin.limit((csvOuterJoin.count*.7).toInt)
```

`limit` operation is not designed for large scale operations and it moves all records to a single partition:

```scala
val df = spark.range(0, 10000, 1, 1000)
df.rdd.partitions.size
```

```
Int = 1000
```

```scala
// Take all records by limit
df.orderBy($"id").limit(10000).rdd.partitions.size
```

```
Int = 1
```

You can use `RDD` API:

```
val ordered = df.orderBy($"utcDate")
val cnt = df.count * 0.7

val train = spark.createDataFrame(ordered.rdd.zipWithIndex.filter {
  case (_, i) => i <= cnt 
}.map(_._1), ordered.schema)

val test = spark.createDataFrame(ordered.rdd.zipWithIndex.filter {
  case (_, i) => i > cnt 
}.map(_._1), ordered.schema)
```

Comment: In spark 1.6.1 shell, I get the following error:  <console>:60: error: not found: value spark

Comment: `sparkContext.createDataFrame()` worked and finally your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`coalesce(1,false)` means merging all data into one partition, aka keeping 40GB data in memory of one node.

Never try to get all data in one file by `coalesce(1,false)`.
Instead, you should just call saveAsTextFile(so the output looks like part-00001, part00002, etc.) and then merge these partition files outside.
The merge operation depends on your file system. In case of HDFS, you can use http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge

Comment: I do not reach this point of the code. Java heap space error occur in collect stage. Thank you for the info though.