# How to efficiently query a hive table in spark using hive context?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have a 1.6T Hive table with time series data. I am using `Hive 1.2.1`
and `Spark 1.6.1` in `scala`.

Following is the query which I have in my code. But I always get `Java out of memory error`.

```
val sid_data_df = hiveContext.sql(s"SELECT time, total_field, sid, year, date FROM tablename WHERE sid = '$stationId' ORDER BY time LIMIT 4320000  ")
```

By iteratively selecting few records at a time from hive table, I am trying to do a sliding window on the resultant `dataframe`

I have a cluster of 4 nodes with 122 GB of memory, 44 vCores. I am using 425 GB memory out of 488 GB available. I am giving the spark-submit with the following parameters

```
--num-executors 16 --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 22G --executor-cores 10 \
--conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1800" \
--conf "spark.shuffle.memory.fraction=0.6" \
--conf "spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.4" \
--conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2600" \
--conf "spark.yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=123880" \
--conf "spark.yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=43"
```

kindly give me suggestions on how to optimize this and successfully fetch data from hive table.

Thanks

Comment: You have reasonably good configuration. You are running our of memory since you have NOT re-partitioned data ( or if it is re-partitioned then  .... its not to a optimally good number I guess it could be like 16 * 43 * 2 = 1376 or 16 * 43 * 3 = 2064 ). see executor logs and see how many number of records are going to each executor.

Comment: I have repartitioned. But job fails before the repartitioning step. The select query is not efficient I feel. Does the `limit` on the select query works like, it will fetch all records and then apply limit on it?

Comment: there is an answer below have you removed limit and tried ?

Comment: The number of records for each iteration is around 855360000 and thats why i applied limit on it. But, I will try running without limit and update the post here..

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram: By removing limit, the job ran fine. So I understood that I shouldn't use limit. It was capable of querying such a large number of records. But it didn't run successfully. It stopped running after around 30 iterations. I got `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f04e8e50000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12) #                                                                      # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue`

Comment: ok. first Vote-up/accept  the  answer provided  @user6910411. you have still memory issues. try increasing that

Comment: Done. Thanks :)  By increasing the driver memory, I got rid of the memory issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely here:

```
LIMIT 4320000
```

You should avoid using `LIMIT` to subset large number of records. In Spark, `LIMIT` moves all rows to a single partition and is likely to cause serious performance and stability issues.

See for example [How to optimize below spark code (scala)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40855770/6910411)

> I am trying to do a sliding window on this resultant dataframeiteratively by selecting few records at a time.

This doesn't sound right. Sliding window operations can be usually achieved with some combination of window function, and timestamp-based [`window` buckets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@window(timeColumn:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,windowDuration:String,slideDuration:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).