# Spark's Dataset's limit function creates a new Dataset with only 1 partition. Why?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I just realized (after some empirical tests) that applying the `limit` function on a `Dataset` produces a new `Dataset` with only 1 partition. How come ?

I can't find any related questions. And reading the source code on `LocalLimit` and `GlobalLimit` didn't provide any insight as I'm not familiar with the internals.

This can be problematic as one might want to use something like `limit(1000000)` for whatever reason.

Comment: Just a few related threads - https://stackoverflow.com/q/51465806/10465355, http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Limit-Query-Performance-Suggestion-td20570.html, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45886205/10465355 - TLDR; that is the expected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Check the value of `spark.sparkContext.defaultParallelism`. If not explicitly set it uses the number of available cores as the default value for number of partitions. If you're testing on a single-core machine and creating datasets it would be set to `1`.

If you're concerned about the number of partitions, you can set `spark.default.parallelism` to a higher number and/or invoke `repartition()` on your dataset.

Comment: The value was not explicitly set but during my tests there were multiple cores on each slave, so it must be something else.

Comment: I can't really think of anything else other than if you're using Docker to run your Spark cluster you should check the CPU/resources you've given the Docker engine. To avoid the default partitioning becoming problematic you should make explicit calls to `repartition()`. That's really the solution to solve any parallelism issues.